# Asymptotics of ${2n \choose n+k} {2n \choose n}^{-1}$ when $k$ grows with $n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-and-convergence

The quotient $Q(n,k) := \frac{{2n \choose n+k}}{{2n \choose n}}$ clearly converges to one for  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed and $n \rightarrow \infty$. Simultaneously it converges to zero, if $k$ grows proprotionally to $n$. I am interested in finding a series $(k_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which grows somewhat slowly and with the property that $Q(n,k_n)$ converges to zero somewhat quickly.

**Question:**
If we define a "good set" $S$ consisting of all pairs $(\alpha,\beta) \in (0,1)^2$ such that for $k_n = [n^{1-\alpha}]$ we have $Q(n,k_n) \lesssim \frac{1}{n^{1+\beta}}$, then I am looking for $\underset{(\alpha,\beta) \in S}{\operatorname{argmax}} \min(\alpha,\beta)$.

Simulations indicate that $Q(n,[n^{1-\alpha}])$ converges to one for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ and converges to zero for $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$. Further simulations with $n \leq 10000$ allude to $(0.38,0.38)$ being in $S$ and $(0.4,0.4)$ not being in $S$.

My first approach is using Sterlings formula to get
\begin{align*}
    & Q(n,k) = \frac{{2n \choose n+k}}{{2n \choose n}} = \frac{n! \, n!}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}\\
    & = \frac{n}{\sqrt{(n-k)(n+k)}} \Big( \frac{n}{e} \Big)^{2n} \Big( \frac{e}{n-k} \Big)^{n-k} \Big( \frac{e}{n+k} \Big)^{n+k} (1+\mathcal{O}(1/n))\\
    & = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-k^2}} \Big( \frac{n}{n-k} \Big)^{n-k} \Big( \frac{n}{n+k} \Big)^{n+k} (1+\mathcal{O}(1/n))
\end{align*}
but I am unsure about how to proceed. One can find the limit-representation of the exponential function $e^x = \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \big(1+\frac{x}{m}\big)^m$ in the above formula by writing
\begin{align*}
    & Q(n,k) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2-k^2}} \underbrace{\Big( 1 + \frac{k}{n-k} \Big)^{n-k}}_{\rightarrow e^{k}} \underbrace{\Big( 1 - \frac{k}{n+k} \Big)^{n+k}}_{\rightarrow e^{-k}} (1+\mathcal{O}(1/n)) \ ,
\end{align*}
but the convergence only holds for fixed $k$. With precise knowledge on the asymptotic behaviour of $\big(1+\frac{x}{m}\big)^m$, when $x$ grows with $m$, one should also be able to describe the asymptotic behaviour of $Q(n,k_n)$.

Any help is much apprechiated!

Comment: You stated earlier that you are interested in $k=cn$, and then for example $(n/(n-k))^{n-k} \simeq (1/(1-c))^{(1-c)n}$.

Comment: In order to understand $Q(n,k)$ you can use the Taylor series for $\log (1+x)$. By Taylor expansion (you have to go up to degree-3 Taylor polynomial), you can verify that $(n-k)\log(1+k/(n-k))+(n+k)\log(1 -k/(n+k)) = -k^2 n/(n^2-k^2) (1 + O(k^2/n^2))$ when $k \le cn$ ($c$ sufficiently small), so $$Q(n,k) = \exp(-(1+o(1))k^2/n)$$  when $k =o(n)$.

Comment: Thank you! This implies that all $(\alpha,\alpha)$ are in $S$ as long as $\alpha < 0.5$. The simulations probably couldn't see this, since the convergence to zero is only visible for extremely large $n$.

Comment: One can make more accurate approximations which probably can be detected in the simulations. I don't know what your motivation is, but there is a natural connection to probability. My last comment relates to the $p=q=1/2$ case of the De Moivre–Laplace theorem.

Comment: This is already plenty, thanks. I trust your proof a lot more than my simulations.